# How do I install command line MySQL client on mac?

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I want to install the MySQL client for the command line, not a GUI. I have searched over the web but only found instructions on installing the MySQL server.

Comment: I did that `brew install mysql-client`. What's the next step? I was expecting to get a `mysql` cli option or something. And no mysql is not present in `/usr/local/` directory.

Comment: The `brew install mysql-client` command doesn't install a working MySQL client.

Comment: @AndrewKoster of course it doesn't.  that might actually have made sense :)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

install [MySQLWorkbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), then

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Comment: restart your mac for the path changes to take effect

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer this only works for one session and has to be redone for every single session. (and yes I tried that restarting thing but that didn't work)

Comment: @jonalv Because shell commands can easily be added to one's .bashrc or .bash_profile if one desires any command (such as this one) to be run in every shell on startup.

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer when the question states "Not any GUI"?

Comment: Well this should not really be accepted answer but heck it helped me. I didn't realize Workbench comes with these tools installed.

Comment: @captainblack or just load a new terminal

Comment: Add the line in this answer to ~/.bash_profile and then run `source ~/.bash_profile` or load a new instance of terminal.

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer. First, the initial query asked for a command-line only implementation. Second, and more important, this requires requires Microsoft's .Net Framework 4.5.

Comment: You're taking this too far. You get a GUI _and_ a CLI. Just use the CLI. Put it in your bash rc and you're done.

Comment: I found that the current MySQLWorkbench doesn't contain mysqlsh anymore

Comment: MacOS 11.2 is required

Comment: “MySQLWorkbench” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Comment: This is not even close to an answer, for all of the reasons above. Can we get more reports and downvotes?

Comment: It is still working, and it is a terminal solution. iI is not just very detailed answer. You need to add the line mentioned to your bash_profile like this  `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS' >> ~/.bash_profile` then run `source ~/.bash_profile` (as mentioned in other comments)  then  mysql command is going to work

Comment: As @Daniel mentioned, it's not the most detailed answer. It has already been mentioned how to add it to bash. However, If you use zsh, then simply add the line to ~/.zshrc  and follow same steps (either run source ~/.zshrc or open a new terminal).

Answer (score 137):

This strictly installs a command line client, without the other overhead:

Install Homebrew (if you don't have it):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then, install `mysql-client`:

```
brew install mysql-client
```

Then, add the `mysql-client` binary directory to your PATH:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Finally, reload your bash profile:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you should be able to run `mysql` in a terminal, if not try opening a new terminal

Comment: Use `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` if using default zsh (default in recent macOS)

Comment: If you use _zsh_ instead of _bash_ you should add `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"` to your `~/.zprofile` file.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I can't believe the other answers were even accepted. =0

Comment: On my Catalina Mac, `brew install mysql-client` put the executable into /usr/local/cellar/mysql-client/8.0.27/bin, and to avoid a conflict with the Apple-supplied mysql, it didn't create a symlink in an executable directory. So I created my own symlink: `$ ln -s /usr/local/cellar/mysql-client/8.0.27/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql8`. Having done that, I was able to invoke it with `$ mysql8 -V`. This should work in both bash and zsh.

Comment: this works for me on the macOS Monterey, thank you.

Comment: mac m1, mysql is in `/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/bin/`

Answer (score 91):

If you have already installed MySQL from the disk image (dmg) from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/), open a terminal, run:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

then, reload `.bash_profile` by running following command:

```
 . ~/.bash_profile
```

You can now use `mysql` to connect to any mysql server:

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u username -p
```

Credit & Reference: http://www.gigoblog.com/2011/03/13/add-mysql-to-terminal-shell-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: The OP implied that he did not want to install the server, just the command-line client.

Comment: @JackSparrow You should have read the question first. You answer requires or implies installing mysql server but the question specifically said he did not want to install the server

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The installer should do that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 71):

Best option is:

```
brew install mysql
```

Comment: That installs the server too, what about client only?

Comment: `brew install caskroom/cask/mysql-shell` will install the command line client.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that, if installed this way, the shell is launched with the `mysqlsh` command.

Comment: @Krystian how do you remove mysql-shell created with the above command?

Comment: In the case that the MySQL Community Server was installed before: Be aware that this will make available two different servers on your system, when an upgrade is done make sure you execute the correct binaries.

Comment: Thank you @Krystian & @eric-jorgensen
I modified command to `brew install Caskroom/cask/mysql-shell` cap C for "caskroom" and command used was mysqlsh from

Comment: @Krystian: You should have posted your comment as an answer. +1 for that comment anyway. My MacOS Mojave 10.14.6, needed to run the command `brew install homebrew/cask/mysql-shell` instead.

Comment: This is a poor answer if the question is just asking for the mysql client. Change it.

Comment: What is the diff between `mysql` and `mysql-shell` for `brew`? Maybe `mysql` brings all the tools - import, dump, etc and mysql-shell is for the client. I do `brew install mysql-shell`.

Comment: what is the difference between `brew install mysql` and `brew install mysql-client`?

Comment: @A.Soliman `brew install mysql` installs both the client (used to connect to a db server) and the db server (used to host a db)

Answer (score 39):

Mysql has a client-only set of utilities:

Mysql client shell
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/

Other command line utilities
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/

Mac OSX version available.

Comment: This is the closest to the right answer, considering the OP wanted *client only* and *command line*.  However, user16... and @JackSparrow gave the most useful instructions on what to do after install.

Comment: mysql client is not installed via this method AFAICT

Comment: looks like they broke it out as a separate tool, https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/

Comment: MySQL Shell installs `mysqlsh` which seems to be an equivalent to the classical `mysql` command. You may install it with Homebrew using `brew cask install mysql-shell`.

Comment: If you're expecting a `mysql` prompt, try `mysqlsh --sql` for a similar experience (and it takes mostly the same arguments, helpfully!)

Answer (score 34):

There is now a `mysql-client` formula.

`brew install mysql-client`

Comment: It *does* install mysql command as something like `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/x.x.x/bin/mysql`, which is probably not on PATH. Doing `brew link mysql-client` afterwards worked for me.

Comment: `brew install mysql-client@5.7` for mysql 5.7

Comment: thanks @alx the link got it working for me. however, i had to do `brew link mysql-client@5.7` since that was the version i installed via homebrew.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Though after install I had to add this to my .zshrc file: `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 10):

For installing `mysql-shell` with homebrew, run

```
brew cask install mysql-shell
```

you can then launch the mysql shell with

```
mysqlsh
```

if you want to enter SQL mode directly, run

```
mysqlsh --sql
```

Comment: So there is the maybe silly `js` mode by default and your last code shows how to circumvent, plus one.

Answer (score 7):

Open the "MySQL Workbench" DMG file and

```sh
# Adjust the path to the version of MySQL Workbench you downloaded
cp "/Volumes/MySQL Workbench 6.3.9.CE/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysql" /usr/local/bin
# Make sure it's executable
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

Eject the DMG disk

Comment: This is how I solved the problem by the light your answer shed. Thanks.
```cp /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysql /usr/local/bin```

Comment: I would recommend using a soft link: `ln -s /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysql /usr/local/bin` so that updates are reflected without having to run the copy again.

Answer (score 3):

Installation command from brew:

```
$ brew cask install mysql-shell
```

Look at what you can do:

```
$ mysqlsh --help
```

Run query from `mysqlsh` client installed:

```
$ mysqlsh --host=192.x.x.x --port=3306 --user=user --password=xxxxx

MySQL Shell 8.0.18

Copyright (c) 2016, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates.
Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type '\help' or '\?' for help; '\quit' to exit.
WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Creating a session to 'user@192.x.x.x:3306'
Fetching schema names for autocompletion... Press ^C to stop.
Your MySQL connection id is 16
Server version: 8.0.18 MySQL Community Server - GPL
No default schema selected; 
type \use <schema> to set one.

 MySQL  192.x.x.x:3306 ssl  JS >

 MySQL  192.x.x.x:3306 ssl  JS > `\use rafdb`

Default schema set to `rafdb`.
```

Comment: Newer `brew` syntax is `brew install mysql-shell --cask`.  But why it is listed under the `cask` section? Isn't `cask`  for GUI application? Also this might help: `mysqlsh --host=xxxx --port=3306 --user=xxx --password=xxxx --ssl-mode=DISABLED --sql`

Answer (score 2):

If you installed from the DMG on a mac, it created a mysql client but did not put it in your user path.

Add this to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

This will let you run `mysql` from anywhere as you.

Comment: This worked for me. I installed the MySQL Shell from the MySQL website but still nothing. Fixing the path as directed above did the job. It seems the install did work, but didn't set the path correctly (if at all).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the earlier answer you can get both mysql server and client libs by running

`brew install mysql`.

There is also client only installation. To install only client libraries run

`brew install mysql-connector-c`

In order to run these commands, you need homebrew package manager in your mac. You can install it by running

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Answer (score 1):

Using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) you can install the client with:

```
sudo port install mysql57
```

You also need to select the installed version as your mysql

```
sudo port select mysql mysql57
```

The server is only installed if you append `-server` to the package name (e.g. `mysql57-server`)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to install mysql server or workbench, copy the mysql client somewhere, update your path settings and then delete whatever you installed to get the executable in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql client is available in macOS ports. If you don't have this excellent third party package manager already installed, it is available from here: https://www.macports.org/

Once you have installed macports, open a terminal and make sure everything is up to date:

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

There are multiple different versions of MySQL and mariadb (community fork of MySQL) available in the ports repos. List available versions using the following command:

```
port search 'mariadb*'
```

I recommend choosing mariadb over mysql as it is, mostly, a drop in replacement (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) and has excellent community support.

If applicable, choose which version of mariadb you want (a list of versions of mariadb is available here: https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/+releases/). If you're not bothered, install the default version:

```
sudo port install mariadb
```

Mariadb (including the mysql-compatible command line client) is now available on your system. On my system, the CLI client resides in the following location:

```
$ /opt/local/bin/mysql --version
/opt/local/bin/mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for osx10.15 (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

It's obviously a bit inconvenient to type out the full path, */opt/local/bin/mysql* each time you want to use the client. Ports has already thought of this problem. To view available versions of mysql on your system, run:

```
$ port select mysql

Available versions for mysql:
mariadb (active)
none
```

Choose one from the list. For example, to use mariadb as the default mysql client:

```
sudo port select mysql mariadb
```

Now open a fresh terminal window and you should be able to start the mariadb mysql CLI client:

```
mysql -h <hostname> -u <username> -p
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but for me Brew put the binaries at:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.33_1/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing here a bit in 2024 but for my m1 mac:

```
brew install mysql-client
```

then

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

The second command was necessary, if only I would have read the prompts from brew itself...

Answer (score -1):

if you need a lighter solution i recommend mysql-shell, install using the command below.

brew cask install mysql-shell

To start after installation type ***mysqlsh***.