# django running on local machine cannot connect to docker container running MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker

Hi all so i'm attempting to run django on my local machine to connect to a docker container running mysql but keep getting an error when attempting to install mysqlclient via pip. First i got this error when attempting to install `mysqlclient` :

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/8d/xdwdnphs1w5b_vtxrc67__5h0000gn/T/pip-build-mejs2ys1/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/8d/xdwdnphs1w5b_vtxrc67__5h0000gn/T/pip-build-mejs2ys1/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/private/var/folders/8d/xdwdnphs1w5b_vtxrc67__5h0000gn/T/pip-build-mejs2ys1/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
```

Then i went ahead and installed `mysql-connector-c`via brew. I reran `pip install mysqlclient` and now i get this error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/8d/xdwdnphs1w5b_vtxrc67__5h0000gn/T/pip-build-8wu06grt/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/8d/xdwdnphs1w5b_vtxrc67__5h0000gn/T/pip-build-8wu06grt/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/8d/xdwdnphs1w5b_vtxrc67__5h0000gn/T/pip-build-8wu06grt/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in <listcomp>
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/8d/xdwdnphs1w5b_vtxrc67__5h0000gn/T/pip-build-8wu06grt/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

Has anyone come across the error when attempting to run django on localmachine while connecting to mysql running in a docker container?

Comment: remove `mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz` file from `/var/cache/apt/archieves`

Comment: @AvinashRaj but im running mysql in docker. Do i need to install mysql on my localhost to run django app from local machine to connect to the docker container running mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using macOS, try this code below:

```
brew remove mysql-connector-c
brew install mysql
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

This will work for you.

Comment: but im running mysql in docker. Do i need to install mysql on my localhost to run django app from local machine to connect to the docker container running mysql

Comment: Trust me, this is the `simplist` way to do. `mysqlclient` python packages depends on C lib in `mysql` package, so this way is the `simplist` way to do.

Comment: Sure there are more options like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990488/how-do-i-install-command-line-mysql-client-on-mac/35338119 , but I recommend the best way for you. And one thing more, it doesn't mean `running mysql server` when you do `brew install mysql` :)

Comment: thanks but now im running into an error as i tried your suggestion

Comment: the error i receive is `ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`