# Django: python manage.py createdb Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.20.dylib

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm almost new with django.

When I sent to the terminal on the django project with `python manage.py createdb`, I had an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 26, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/{ItIsMyName}/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

I also had an error on python shell

```
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Sep 21 2017, 18:29:43)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/masanarimakino/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/masanarimakino/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/masanarimakino/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I searched similar question again and again on stackoverflow. But none of them are error on django.

Here, I almost tend to understand the cause of the error, it is mysql's version-up.

But I don't know how to fix that.

So, please tell me how to fix that.

In addition, I already have installed mysqlclient now. (version 1.3.13)

Here is each versions and environments.
Environments
pc: mac os 10.13.1

Versions
python: 3.6.2
mezzanine: 4.3.1
django: 1.11.16
mysqlclient: 1.3.13

---

New error 1

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz (90kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 3.2MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/j6/g61rgqwj27z30t9xsxpyqj_00000gn/T/pip-install-ntfyq9j4/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/j6/g61rgqwj27z30t9xsxpyqj_00000gn/T/pip-install-ntfyq9j4/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 60, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/j6/g61rgqwj27z30t9xsxpyqj_00000gn/T/pip-install-ntfyq9j4/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 60, in <listcomp>
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/j6/g61rgqwj27z30t9xsxpyqj_00000gn/T/pip-install-ntfyq9j4/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 13, in dequote
        raise Exception("Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 ?")
    Exception: Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 ?

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/j6/g61rgqwj27z30t9xsxpyqj_00000gn/T/pip-install-ntfyq9j4/mysqlclient/
```

Comment: "Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?"

Comment: Oh... sorry for lack of my explanation.  I already have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Linux os then you need to install one more package to your os:

Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

[reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Mac Os:

```
brew install mysql
```

[Mac os libmysqlclient-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857861/libmysqlclient15-dev-on-macs)

[Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990488/how-do-i-install-command-line-mysql-client-on-mac)

or if Windows

[Windows libmysqlclient-dev](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Installing-and-configuring-the-MySQL-Client-on-Windows-s.html)

Comment: Sorry for lack of my explanation.. My OS is mac os.

Comment: Thank you! Solved!