MySQL not accepting root password
I am trying to follow a tutorial and I cannot get MySQL to work. I apparently already had it downloaded but could not for the life of me remember the password for root. When I tried to follow various instructions on resetting the password I kept hitting a wall. So I figured the best solution would be to uninstall MySQL (I don't know how to use it so it's not like there were any databases associated with it).
Anyway, I uninstalled it and restarted the computer. New download. And still: [28000][1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
I just want to continue with the tutorial... please can someone advise. I understand I could use SQLite or something else, but I am trying to follow a specific online course.
I am on MacOS 14.5 (Sonoma) and downloaded mysql-9.0.0-macos14-x86_64.dmg
I also tried with MySQL 8.0.38. Installation is fine and there are no problems. It asks me to enter a root password, which I do, but then it won't accept that root password.
Edit: This is when trying to connect using DataGrip (free trial as per the tutorial) but also happens in the CL:
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


I don't know about Macos - but reinstalling should work. do you get the same error if you uninstall it and try? as in before you reinstall... (hint: there may be more than one mysql installation)

@JoSSte yes i get the same error message. how would i check if there are other mysql installations?

if it taking much of your time to debug, re-install as a quick solution with different tutorial- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990488/how-do-i-install-command-line-mysql-client-on-mac
https://medium.com/@rodolfovmartins/how-to-install-mysql-on-mac-959df86a5319

if it gives that message there is a mysql server installed - otherwise you would get a timeout or not listening error. I am not aware how or where to check - i use linux andd windoze

I thought initial installations did not have a root password, so inputting one would never work. Try without a password first.
If not, you can reset the root password from the docs. Their recommendation for finding the pid is probably a good one as you might (somehow) have 2 instances running, or 2 different installs.
